# Why does Firefox block Iframe content - even in Safe Mode (with all addons disabled)

Tags: firefox

Since a while Firefox blocks IFrame contents, like youtube videos, foreign content in newspapers, or even iframes in the Mozilla documentation:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Just updated to version 75, but happened with 74 and I guess even before as well.

Comment: the analysis of the problem was disturbed by browser cache effects. Plugins modified the page content that was then cached. Restarting the browser in Safe mode still caused the cached but modified content to be accessed, therefore the Safe Mode was affected by (now nonactive) plugins.

Comment: The Iframes inside Mozially MDN certainly show up with having the default setting security.mixed_content.block_active_content = true. It was a plugin issue, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The same question has been asked at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18373592/1256347) in 2013 and showed up at the top after a search for `firefox iframe not working`.

The [highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18767241/1256347) states that Firefox does not show iframes on https sites. Please follow the link for the full answer and a possible workaround.

Comment: I saw this post, but it does not explain the behavior. Because on most machines the Iframes do show up. Your analysis would mean that since 6 years nobody can watch Mozilla MDN or Youtube Videos without special handling. That is not the case. On other machines Firefox displays those Iframes. So I assume there is a setting. How is the behavior on your machine? Do you use Firefox?

Comment: but i have to admit that setting security.mixed_content.block_active_content to false solves the problem, will check that setting on the other machines.

Comment: Well the `why` I don't know (and that wasn't how I read your question), but I tested on my Firefox (v74.0.1, `security.mixed_content.block_active_content = true`) and I _do_ see the iframe on the URL in your question. Perhaps you can edit your question to indicate that you want iframes without special handling?